# What does this relation represents ?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, computer-science, relations, equivalence-relations

so i have a hard time understanding what would this relation looks like, we aren't given any precise function so it's hard to know what this would look like. We have to establish the relation and then say if it's an equivalence relation and give the differents equivalence classes.
My representation of this relation would be : ${ <0,0> , <1,1>, <2,2>, <3,3> }$ but im not quite sure if i'm right. Then i would say it is an equivalence relation but we cannot define the different classes since we aren't given any function.
Here's the function and the relation R that we have to create ( N represents natural numbers) :

f: N$\,\to\,${0,1,2,3} a function. Construct the relation R included in $N^2$ the relation ( has the same image by f) which means :  [image]

Thank you for your help !!

Comment: This is a well-known equivalence relation whose elements (equivalence classes) are called fibers.

Comment: Is my understanding of it good ? The relation would be ${<0,0>,<1,1>,<2,2><3,3>}$ and its an equivalence relation but since we aren't given any specific function we cannot define the differents equivalence classes ? thank you

Answer (score 1):

It concerns a relation on $\mathbb N$ (so not on $\{0,1,2,3\}$ as you seem to think).

The equivalence classes form a partition of set $\mathbb N$ and the class that is represented by element $n\in\mathbb N$ is the set:$$[n]=\{m\in\mathbb N\mid f(m)=f(n)\}$$

The number of equivalence classes corresponds with the cardinality of the image of $f$.

This because the classes take the shape: $$\{n\in\mathbb N\mid f(n)=i\}$$ where $i$ ranges over the image of $f$.

---

More generally *any* equivalence relation $R$ on *any* set $X$ can be presented like this.

If $P$ denotes the set of equivalence classes of $R$ then we can prescribe function $\nu:X\to P$ by $x\mapsto[x]$ where $[x]$ denotes the equivalence class that is represented by $x$.

Then automatically we have:$$\forall,y\in X\; [xRy\iff \nu(x)=\nu(y)]$$

Answer (score 0):

Your answer makes no sense, because $R$ is an equivalence relation in $\mathbb N$, not in $\{0,1,2,3\}$.

You should check that $R$ is an equivalence relation (that's easy). Then there are (at most) $4$ equivalence classes:

- $\{n\in\mathbb{N}\,|\,f(n)=0\}$;
- $\{n\in\mathbb{N}\,|\,f(n)=1\}$;
- $\{n\in\mathbb{N}\,|\,f(n)=2\}$;
- $\{n\in\mathbb{N}\,|\,f(n)=3\}$.

Of course, each of these sets is really an equivalence class when it is not empty. In particular, there are $4$ equivalence classes if and only if $f$ is surjective.

Comment: Ohhh makes sens now correct me if im wrong but i would write the 4 classes like that ?:- $\{n,m\in\mathbb{N}\,|\,f(n)=f(m)=0\}$;
 - $\{n,m\in\mathbb{N}\,|\,f(n)=f(m)=1\}$;
 - $\{n,m\in\mathbb{N}\,|\,f(n)=f(m)=2\}$;
 - $\{n,m\in\mathbb{N}\,|\,f(n)=f(m)=3\}$.